# Synchronization between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm a student and I want to understand synchronization between threads.

I have two threads t1 and t2.

I have a shared piece of memory between them.

```
/*e.g.*/ std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
```

One thread let's say t1 is reading data, and the other is writing..

```
std::mutex mu; //is used for synchronization

std::string read_1(std::string key)
{
    return data[key];
}

std::string read_2(std::string key)
{
    mu.lock();
    return data[key];
    mu.unlock();
}

void write(std::string key, std::string value)
{
    mu.lock();
    data[key] = value;
    mu.unlock();
}
```

read_1 is it thread safe?

if not what's the best way to optimize this code?

thanks.

Comment: No, `read_1` is not thread-safe. I'm not sure what code is "this code" - you haven't shown much of it.

Comment: Also, `read_2` is broken - it locks the mutex, but doesn't unlock it. `mu.unlock()` is never reached. This will lead to undefined behavior very soon.

Comment: Use something like [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) instead of locking/unlocking your mutexes manually.

Comment: `data` is undefined ...

Comment: Just read over the [`<mutex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/mutex) header

Comment: We really can't answer *if not what's the best way to optimize this code?* since we don't actually know how you are using it.

Comment: There are multiple ways to optimize this code depending on the context. The most efficient way is to entirely remove mutexes. Which will work **if** whenever a write happens then nothing else happens. Locking every operation (via lock_guard/unique_lock of course) is another option. Maybe reader-writer lock will be more efficient (depending on writers/readers ratio). Another one is to use some concurrent collection, perhaps lock-free.

Comment: @freakish, Re, "Which will work if whenever a write happens..." I thought it was _undefined behavior_ when two threads access the same memory location without any locking or other memory barriers. I am sure that it might behave the way a naive programmer would expect it to behave, on _some_ platform, if there always is a quiescent period between accesses by different threads; but I don't believe that the language standard _guarantees_ that it will work that way. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Shared memory read without lock is not UB. It is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Sure. I guess I should have said, "...and at least one of the accesses is an update..." I didn't think that was necessary in this context because the original question quite explicitly says that at least one thread is updating the data structure.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but it doesn't say if updates happen **at the same time** as reads. If they don't (somehow you guarantee that in your app) then you don't need a mutex. That's why I said: either 1 writer, 0 readers **or** any number of readers at one time.

Comment: @freakish. I don't know the C++ standard on that level, and I don't have time to look it up, but in other languages (e.g., in Java), what you said is not true.  If one thread in a Java program updates some variables, and then some time later, another thread examines the same variables with no "synchronization;" then the second thread may see some, or none, or all of the updates.  And, if it sees only some updates, then it may see a later update, but not an earlier one. The same technical reasons for that behavior are valid for any language, so I would expect C/C++ to have similar rules.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Hmm, I've started doubting myself now. Perhaps you do need memory barriers in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `read_1` is *not* thread safe. It needs to lock the mutex before accessing `data`.

This would be safe;

```
std::string read_1(std::string key)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
    return data[key];
}
```

Also; your `read_2` function is broken. It returns before unlocking the mutex. If you had used a `std::lock_guard` then you wouldn't have had that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What's the best solution to optimize this as far as write() + read_2() is not optimized?

Comment: @RogerWorld The only way to avoid the mutex is to rewrite your entire algorithm. For instance, you could have separate maps and occasionally merge them as needed. Depends on what you need to ultimately do.

Comment: @RogerWorld What needs optimizing? Have you profiled the code and determined that this is a hot-spot? If not, just keep it simple and lock the mutex before any access to `data`.

Answer (score 1):

> read_1 is it thread safe?

No, it's reading when there could be a write to that data.

> if not what's the best way to optimize this code?

Use a [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @paul evans for your help. Why shared_mutex? I can use mutex as proposed by in the first comment.

Comment: Because with `std::shared_mutex` you have two levels of access: *shared* where multiple read threads can share access to the mutex, and *exclusive* where a single write thread has exclusive access to that mutex.